# delete similar elements in an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, swap

I have the following array

```
a3 = [["a", "b"], ["a","c"], ["b","c"], ["b", "a"], ["c","b"]]
```

I want to get the following output `[["a","b"], ["a","c"], ["b","c"]]` and delete `["b","a"] and ["c","b"]`

I have the following code

```
a3.each do |ary3|
x = ary3[0]
y = ary3[1]
x = ary3[1]
y = ary3[0]
if a3.include?([x,y])
   a3 - [y,x]
   end
end
print a3
```

I tried using the swap, but no luck!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two arrays are considered to be equal if they contain the same elements and these elements are in the same order:

```
["a", "b"] == ["b", "a"]
#=> false

["a", "b"] == ["a", "b"]
#=> true
```

So you need to sort the inner arrays first and then you can use `Array#uniq` to ensure that each element in the outer array will only appear once:

```
arr = [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["c", "b"]]
arr.map(&:sort).uniq
#=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

This will leave `arr` untouched, however:

```
arr
#=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["c", "b"]]
```

You will need to use mutator methods (with a `!`) to edit the array in place:

```
arr = [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["c", "b"]]
arr.map!(&:sort).uniq!
arr
#=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

### Edit

As a follow-up to @sawa's comment, who was concerned that it may not be desirable to change the ordering of the inner arrays, i looked a bit deeper into `Array#uniq`. Consider the following array:

```
arr = [["b", "a"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["c", "b"]]
```

I figured out that `Array#uniq` actually takes a block that lets you specify how the elements should be be compared:

```
arr.uniq!{|x| x.sort }
arr
#=> [["b", "a"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

Cool thing is, this also works with `Symbol#to_proc` (the `&:` notation) and actually looks even more elegant than my original answer:

```
arr.uniq!(&:sort)
arr
#=> [["b", "a"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

You can still use `Array#sort!` if you want the inner arrays to be sorted afterwards:

```
arr.uniq!(&:sort!)
arr
#=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

My last observation on this is though, that the order probably isn't important or else two arrays with different order would not be considered equal. This got me thinking (again) and i posed myself the question: Why not use a `Set`? It would work like this:

```
require 'set'

sets = [Set["a", "b"], Set["a", "c"], Set["b", "c"], Set["b", "a"], Set["c", "b"]]
sets.uniq!
sets
#=> [#<Set: {"a", "b"}>, #<Set: {"a", "c"}>, #<Set: {"b", "c"}>]
```

Just keep in mind that a Set will not allow you to add the same element multiple times, whereas an array does:

```
[%w[a b b b c], %w[a b b b c], %w[a b c]].uniq(&:sort)
#=> [["a", "b", "b", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]

[Set.new(%w[a b b b c]), Set.new(%w[a b b b c]), Set.new(%w[a b c])].uniq
#=> [#<Set: {"a", "b", "c"}>]
```

Comment: This returns an element that was not in the original array. For example, `arr = [["b", "a"]]` becomes `[["a", "b"]]`. Is this intended?

Comment: Nothing is ever perfect ;)

Comment: @padde I did some benchmark, surprisingly my one gives first output  than you. :)

Comment: thanks a lot for putting so much effort with such detailed description. I want to accept both your answers! Cant choose!

Comment: Accept the answer that you actually used to solve the problem. After all, SO is not about getting as much rep as possible, but about helping people and giving back to the community ;)

Comment: @RubyLovely yours is faster because it only reverses the inner arrays whereas mine sorts them. This needs more comparisons.

Comment: Here's the source of both methods for reference: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_0/array.c#L2291 (sort), https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_0/array.c#L2044 (reverse). No wonder mine is a bit slower ;-)

Answer (score 0):

check this one: [`#delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) as below:

```
a3 = [["a", "b"], ["a","c"], ["b","c"], ["b", "a"], ["c","b"]]
p a3.delete_if{|x| [["b", "a"], ["c","b"]].include? x}
#=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

***As per your comment and description post :***

```
a3 = [["a", "b"], ["a","c"], ["b","c"], ["b", "a"], ["c","b"],["b", "a"]]
p a3.each {|x| a3.delete(x.reverse) if a3.include? x.reverse}
#=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]]
```

***BenchMark:***

```
require 'benchmark'
N = 10000


Benchmark.bm(20) do | x |
  a3 = [["a", "b"], ["a","c"], ["b","c"], ["b", "a"], ["c","b"],["b", "a"]]
  x.report('Mine') do
    N.times { a3.each {|x| a3.delete(x.reverse) if a3.include? x.reverse} }
  end
  a3 = [["a", "b"], ["a","c"], ["b","c"], ["b", "a"], ["c","b"],["b", "a"]]
  x.report('padde') do
    N.times { a3.uniq!(&:sort!) }
  end

end
```

***Output:***

```
                           user     system      total        real

Mine                   0.172000   0.000000   0.172000 (  0.361021)
padde                  0.203000   0.000000   0.203000 (  0.460026)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! Is there a way to generalize it and not just for ["b", "a"], ["c","b"] ?

Comment: @reko couldn't understand your point. :( but yes you have to feed your main array about the information that,which objects you want to delete from the source array.

Comment: thanks a lot for putting so much effort with such detailed description. I want to accept both your answers! Cant choose!

Comment: Your code won't work with an arbitrary order, right? Keep that in mind.

Comment: The input `[["a", "b"], ["a", "b"]]` will produce `[["a", "b"], ["a", "b"]]` again. So your solution will only work if you can be sure that the duplicates are always in the reverse order!

Comment: Your benchmark is essentially useless because from the second iteration on, a3 is already free of duplicates.

Comment: @padde Good point. But OP didn't mentioned any such thing, he just wanted to delete entries which are in reverse order. If he/she mentioned I would think about that.

Comment: Another benchmark here tells me mine is 10 percent faster than yours: https://gist.github.com/padde/5433922. So, benchmarks can differ significantly and we should not rely on them. In the end, the OP has to decide which works best for him, i.e. which fits his needs and which one runs faster in his particular use case.

Comment: I've to admit that the estimated error is ±10% so my benchmark is essentially useless, too.

Comment: @padde It's OK. No issue, both meets their whole purpose,that's all. so chill. :)

Comment: I'm just saying that detecting a duplicate by checking if there's another one in reverse order doesn't seem like a good idea. I hope you didn't take anything personally, i'm viewing this as a healthy discussion ;-)